# Как заполнить столбцы DataGridView с помощью массива?

Tags: c#, datagrid, массивы

Мне часто приходиться заполнять столбцы DataGridView примерно следующим содержимым:
Б Б Б Б Б П П Б Б

Я это делаю так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
  this.dgv[i, 0].Value = "Б";

for (int i = 5; i < 7; i++ )
  this.dgv[i, 0].Value = "П";

for (int i = 7; i < 9; i++ )
  this.dgv[i, 0].Value = "Б";
```

Может есть способ по легче? Например можно ли как-то создать массив (`string[] record = { "Б", "Б", "Б", "Б", "Б", "П", "П", "Б", "Б" };`) и с ним заполнить столбцы?

Answer (score 2):

Речь про Windows Forms?
Если количество столбцов известно и постоянно, но создаете их в редакторе для DataGridView, затем объединяете данные в один массив и вставляете **this.dataGridView.Rows.Add(array)**.

```
    this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    foreach(var array in arrays)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(array);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще и таким образом. Однако жаль, что нельзя DataGridView1.DataSource = array; а требуются такие сложные манипуляции. Почему?

```
string[] record = { "Б", "Б", "Б", "Б", "Б", "П", "П", "Б", "Б" };
dataGridView1.DataSource = record.Select(str => new { Name = str }).ToList();
```

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.